# Drawing a 2d convex hull shape on a 3d terrain

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, convex-hull

I have a 3d mesh, which is a terrain. This runs perfectly fine btw, but I want to have shapes moving accross this terrain. These shapes are flat on the landscape and are blob-like: They can change shape and should follow the contoures and the heightmap of the terrain. These shapes can be painted on the landscape or flow over it, that doesn't matter.

The shapes are meant to be blocks of armies moving across the map, and this should be happening Real-Time! Also: they are 2d convex hull shapes. Also they are just one color with an alpha value (like blue with alpha 0.25f).

The only problem is: I can't figure out how to do this and the question is: Can anyone tell me how to do it?

My first thoughts were just to copy the terrain vertex matrix, push it up a bit so it will be on top of the terrain, load this buffer into a VBO and update the index buffer according to the position and shape needed and then draw the shape. This is rather slow and inefficient, especially when the shape is moving and changing. Also, the resolution of the heightmap is 175x175, so the movement is not at all smooth but rather jaggy.

Then I thought, but rather new to this area, update the shape outlines to the fragment shader of the terrain and let the shader decide if a point lies in that area and change color accordingly. This also was a really slow option, but if anyone sees potential and a good way to do this, tell me!

The next option was to draw directly onto the texture, which is still in the failing stage. If someone has any good ideas on how to draw a scene to a flat area and then put that on a terrain mesh, that would be great!

So if anyone has a solution to draw a shape (or multiple) on a terrain? That would be awesome. Thanks in advance!